# Angular Material: 'completed' does not work after reset

Tags: angular, material-design

When `mat-step` is once completed (the `completed` property is set to true) and the stepper is then resetted, `completed` flag works no more (user cannot move to next step).

What should be done to make this working?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-step-complete-ufcxsn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your completed1 and completed2 values stay true even after resetting mat-horizontal-stepper. You need to reset/set those values to false before stepper.reset();